# Input format for proto-spaCy 500 line of Python English parser

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, spacy

I am seeking to understand the [A simple Python dependency parser](https://gist.github.com/syllog1sm/10343947) written by Matthew Honnibal and described in his blog post [Parsing English in 500 Lines of Python](https://explosion.ai/blog/parsing-english-in-python), but I am unclear as to the format of the input files required.

The arguments to the `main()` function, as well as a directory to store the model, are three input files:

1. `train_loc` is a training set of dependency parsed sentences
2. `heldout_in` is the held-out test set of POS-tagged sentences
3. `heldout_gold` is the same held-out sentences dependency parsed

From reading the source code it appears that `train_loc` and `heldout_gold` are in a CONLL format, although I am unsure which one. I am also unsure what is the format of the POS tagged file `heldout_in`.

I have downloaded the Penn treebank datasets "Dependency Parsed Treebank" and "Penn Treebank Sample" from the NLTK Corpora page for the dependency parsed and POS-tagged inputs respectively, but neither of these is accepted as input by the parser, producing tuple unpacking errors.

I am quite happy to work on understanding the code and converting the files I have downloaded into a format that the parser will accept, but wondered if the format was widely known and if files of the correct format are already available.